# Git repository of subfolder

Tags: git, repository, subdirectory

I have a project which has a repository.
I have the root folder of the repo,

```
/A
  /A1
  /A2
/B
  /B1
```

I want to seperate the A folder into a different repository, then I want another repository, which looks exactly the same as the one described above, but with instead of folder A, I want folder A to be a submodule of the repository which I just created. So that A is an independent project, and the other repo depends on submodule A, but also contains B.

How should I do that? Or do I have to create a whole new project with losing all commits?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repository and use `git filter-branch` to remove the history you don't want from both the repositories. After that, you can add A as a submodule to B.

Edit: After following the github guide, do

`git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf A" --prune-empty HEAD` to remove history of A from B.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) SO question has a comprehensive answer.